# Magento setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping') observer event

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I need to display the shipping notice in cart. In order to display the notice I've set the shipping method using php in an observer:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setCountryId('DE')->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')->save();
```

The event I used is "add_to_cart_before":

```
<add_to_cart_before>
    <observers>
        <add_to_cart_before>
            <class>dispatcher/observer</class>
            <method>hookToAddToCartBefore</method>
        </add_to_cart_before>
    </observers>
</add_to_cart_before>
```

The problem is that this event is fired after the shipping notice is read by magento. So in fact the notice appears but only if you refresh the page using F5.

Which cart event could I hook in order to set the shipping method before magento reads it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no events is exits name of `add_to_cart_before`.

You can use other event like:

- checkout_cart_save_before
- checkout_cart_add_product_complete
  etc

Comment: add_to_cart_before was a custom observer from an Ichoo module. checkout_cart_save_before fired before

Comment: If somebody needs it the module is here:http://inchoo.net/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/

Comment: For checkout page what event need to use, check what are all the shipping methods available before place an order. @Amit

Comment: before Order means which checkout step?